# Vue.js: Computed value handling

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a child component that extends LPolygon from the Vue2Leaflet library.

There are a couple properties on LPolygon, let's take the color property for simplicity.

It is set in markup like `<l-polygon :color="foo">`  in which case, color is set by the parent component.

I want to do some iterating and then based on the data contained in `x`, I want to set the color of the l-polygon component.

How to do this?

Here is a fuller example:

```
<template v-for="x in foo">
  <l-polygon v-for="y in bar" v-if="x.id == y.id" :color="COMPUTE_THIS">
  </l-polygon> 
</template>
```

Where, COMPUTE_THIS should be a function that can take data out of `x` and `y` and return a value.

One thought I had is to extend LPolygon component and bind the x and y object into it as props.  But I don't know how to thereafter modify the LPolygon.color property.  If I try to do that, vue complains about direct modification of the prop.

Comment: `:color="someMethod(x, y)"` where `someMethod` is defined as a method on the vue-component responsible for above template?

Comment: @Geert-Jan that was a good lead, thank you